# how do I check if I have the same variable inside two arrays, python, tkinter

Tags: python

I am trying to make a 20 questions game and I'm having trouble getting it to check if I have a certain variable inside of two different arrays.

Example:

```
wins = 0

loses = 0
def updateQandA(*args):
global wins, loses, answers, correctanswers
if correctanswers != answers:
    loses += 1
    if correctanswers == answers:
        wins += 1
answers = [Answers4, Answers8, Answers12
```

These variable do exist in my code:

```
correctanswers = [A2, A5,A10, A15, A20, A24, A25]
answers1 = OptionMenu(root, var, *Answers4, command = updateQandA).grid()
```

There are two arrays with a menu button and 4 options. One of the options in this option menu is A2. What is happening is that no matter what I pick, it just adds one to `loses`. The goal is to get it to where it recognizes that there is a correct answer in one of the 4 options and when I choose the correct answer, it adds one to `wins`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: It sounds like your problem is independent of the GUI.  If so, then get that code out of your posting (this is part of the MCVE process).  You're not clear about the correspondence between your variable names and the noun phrases you use; without a self-consistent example, it's hard to figure out what you're trying to do, since your words keep changing focus.

Comment: As a kick-start, I think that part of your problem is likely that you haven't learned to identify one choice appearing in a group.  Perhaps something like `if single_answer in correct_answers` will help you clarify the remaining problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, and all you want to do is check whether the answer exists in the other array, you could use a for loop with an if statement:

```
for ans in answers:
    if ans in correctanswers:
        wins += 1
    else:
        loses += 1
```

If both arrays are of the same length, and the index in 'answer' corresponds with the index in 'correctanswer', you can use range():

```
for i in range(len(answers)):
    if answers[i] == correctanswers[i]:
        wins += 1
    else:
        loses += 1
```